# Powerpoint: Linking Excel charts & updating them or deleting old charts & inserting updated ones?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation containing Excel charts and .png files. This presentation needs to be updated fairly often and I’d like to use VBA for this. However, I’ve read up on linking charts from Excel to Powerpoint and it seems not to be bug-free, but I don't really know anything about it.

So I need advice what makes the most sense because I don't have any experience with this. Is updating the charts usually not an issue? Or would it be more fool-proof to delete the old charts and insert the new ones? In case it's the latter, would I simply define the dimensions of the chart or does the use of placeholders offer any advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in the past is use VBA to paste pictures of the charts into the slides. Then the presentation serves as a snapshot, and I don't need to worry about links.

You can set up a table with details like chart name, worksheet name, slide number, image size (width, height) and position (left, top). Then the code moves down the list, finding the worksheet, copying the chart, activating the slide, pasting the chart as a picture, moving it into position. Best results are when the chart is sized right in Excel so you don't need to resize it in PowerPoint.

It's been a while, so I don't have that code at my fingertips. I'll hunt around when I have a chance.